# Solve ESLint exhaustive without creating infinite re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

So I recently added ESLint and I'm kind of new to hooks.
But I get a problem with this `useEffect` hook, because ESLint want me to send in `values`, which i use in `setValues` but if I send in values, I get stuck in an infinite loop, while if I don't it works but then I get this warning and I'm thinking there must be a way to solve this without disabling it?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const initCategories = () => {
        getCategories().then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
                const categoryOptions = createOptions(data);
                setCategories(categoryOptions);
            }
        });
    };

    const initTags = () => {
        getTags().then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
                const tagOptions = createOptions(data);
                setTags(tagOptions);
            }
        });
    };

    const formData = new FormData();

    if (body) {
        formData.set('body', body);
    }

    setValues({ ...values, formData });

    initCategories();
    initTags();
}, [body, values]);
```

Because I don't really want it to rerun everytime `values` changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) when you are setting your state.

```
setValues(prev => ({...prev, error: data.error}))
```

So, linter doesn't warn you in this case and you can update your state. Actually, with or without linter, this should be the way when you update your state if you are using the current one.